# How do i enter n inputs,where n is user input in python?

Tags: python-3.x

user enter the range of input for eg:-n=input()
now i want to make a array or list having n inputs?how can this be done?

I have tried for loop but I want something much one line compact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
n = int(input('enter num of inputs: '))
my_list = [input('enter input #%s: ' % i) for i in range(n)]

print(my_list)
```

If you really want a one liner (which is not always a good thing, think about readability first):

```
my_list = [input('enter input #%s: ' % i) for i in range(int(input('enter num of inputs: ')))]
```

Comment: what does %i denotes?

Comment: `%` applied to a string is the old-style string formatting operator, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting